# Rounding double to 4 digit precision has unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, .net

I am rounding a particular double value and expecting a certain result but it isn't coming through. This makes me curious if there is a flaw or am I missing something in the underlying logic.

See the following code snippet:

```
double value = 0.01075;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Produces

```
0.0107
```

Using the AwayFromZero makes me think it should do 0.0108. I have tried several different examples (as seen below) and get the expected result in every instance except the one I listed above. HELP??!

```
double value = 0.010075;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.01008

value = 0.01075;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.0107

value = 0.010750000001;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.0108

value = 0.01065;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.0107

value = 0.01055;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.0106

value = 0.0175;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.018

value = 0.175;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.18

value = 0.75;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(value, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
// 0.8
```

NOTE: Using Visual Studio Pro 2015 with .Net 4.5.2

Comment: Possibly related to [Is floating point math broken?](//stackoverflow.com/q/588004). It works as expected with `decimal` (https://ideone.com/cYT4kq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most decimal numbers can't be represented exactly as floating point numbers. The closest double value to `0.01075` happens to be `0.0107499999999999991395771559155`, at least according to [this calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046048049048055053). That's not the midpoint between `0.0107` and `0.0108`, so the midpoint rounding mode doesn't come into play.

Incidentally, this is why you *never* use floating points for money.

Comment: Well.. That seems to explain the problem. When I convert to decimal then round it seems to work fine. Thanks!